# Azure Devops & Code dependency track integration

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-devops-extensions, owasp-dependency-track

Trying to integrate Dependency track with azure devops and currently we are using bitbucket to dependency track.

I have installed the https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GSoft.dependency-track-vsts this extension already in my project.

Not sure where i can find the extension in azure devops and not sure how to use this extension and complete my integration with Azure Devops.

Regards,
Shan

Installed extension in azure devops project and trying to find the BOM file and YML file to make use of this extension.

Dependency track - https://docs.dependencytrack.org/usage/cicd/

Answer (score 0):

> Not sure where i can find the extension in azure devops and not sure
> how to use this extension and complete my integration with Azure
> Devops.

It's a pipeline task extension, it adds the "`Upload a BOM file to Dependency Track`" task to DevOps. You can find the task when creating a pipeline.

[image]

For the inputs, you can reference the [Parameters](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GSoft.dependency-track-vsts) descripted in the extension overview page or [this GitHub page](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/azure-pipelines-dependency-track/blob/master/README.md).

For the usages, you can reference the **pipeline samples** mentioned in the extension overview page or [this GitHub page](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/azure-pipelines-dependency-track/blob/master/README.md).

[Basic Usage Example:](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/azure-pipelines-dependency-track/blob/master/README.md#basic-usage-example)

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '18.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
    npm install -g @cyclonedx/cyclonedx-npm
  displayName: 'npm install'

- script: |
    cyclonedx-npm --version
    cyclonedx-npm --output-file '$(Agent.TempDirectory)/bom.xml'
  displayName: 'Create BOM'

- task: upload-bom-dtrack-task@1
  displayName: 'Upload BOM to https://dtrack.example.com/'
  inputs:
    bomFilePath: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)/bom.xml'
    dtrackProjId: '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
    dtrackAPIKey: '$(dtrackAPIKey)'
    dtrackURI: 'https://dtrack.example.com/'
```

To understand the Dependency-Track you can reference the following threads:

- [Dependency-Track Introduction](https://docs.dependencytrack.org/)
- [Dependency Track: Analyze your
  vulnerabilities from the use of third-party components](https://geko.cloud/en/dependency-track-analyze-your-vulnerabilities-from-the-use-of-third-party-components/)

**UPDATE:**

I created a C# project and referenced the vulnerable nuget package `System.Text.RegularExpressions@4.3.0`. The vulnerability can be seen after the bom file is uploaded to DT. You can have a try for that.

[image]

Yaml for your reference:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '8.x'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Install CycloneDX
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    custom: 'tool'
    arguments: 'install --global CycloneDX'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Create BOM File
  inputs:
   command: 'custom'
   custom: 'CycloneDX'
   arguments: '-d $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/WebApplication/WebApplication.sln -o $(Agent.TempDirectory)'
- task: upload-bom-dtrack-task@1
  displayName: 'Upload BOM to http://xxx/'
  inputs:
    bomFilePath: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)/bom.xml'
    dtrackProjName: 'WebAPP'
    dtrackProjVersion: 'v1.2'
    dtrackProjAutoCreate: true
    dtrackAPIKey: '$(dtrackAPIKey)'
    dtrackURI: 'http://xxxx:8081'
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. I completed the above steps and able to create a BOM file and new project in dependency track. when ever i pushed the new code to my master the pipeline is getting triggered and generation the bOM file. I uploaded some bad code for testing this extension , pipeline ran successfully but not able to see any vulnerabilities in dependency track application. Is there anything i am missing !

Comment: Not an expert on that, but please double check and make sure the referenced library has a vulnerability, sometimes it will take a while to sync the data. BTW, it seems there are issues with the `DependencyTrack`, similar ticket reported in github, e.g:  https://github.com/DependencyTrack/dependency-track/issues/1546, and https://github.com/DependencyTrack/dependency-track/issues/783

Comment: added many angular dependencies in my code but still no luck :(

Comment: Basically, we have to wait for some time for Dependency-Track to analyze the file once BOM file is uploaded. After some time, the dashboard will get populated, and we can analyze the data. I will check the scenario and update you later.

Comment: @ShanmugamNatarajan I created a c# project and referenced the vulnerable nuget package `System.Text.RegularExpressions@4.3.0`. The vulnerability can be seen after the bom file is uploaded to DT. I have updated the answer, please have a try for that and see if it works for you.